# Gaussian elimination and pivots

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I'm having trouble answering the question posed below ("Question: Which x on the left...").

It seems like there's only 2 options as the first two along the diagonal are already boldfaced. I'm not sure which one and why though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

The $x$ on line 3, column 3, since that is the pivot you will use on next step (provided that is non zero)

Long "picky" one:

The problem is maybe in the usage of the letter $x$ for the whole matrix, since in fact we are considering a matrix of real numbers, which of course can be different, so naming all of them $x$ is weird.

That being said the question is still "hard" to answer. As you have already noticed there are only 2 options, the $x$'s on the third row. The first thing is, we have to suppose that the matrix has maximal rank, so at least one of those $x$'s is different from zero. The second one is that we can choose any $x\neq 0$, but then, without some transformation, the final matrix might not be triangular, that is, if you choose the $x$ on the 4th column you would get:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x & \boldsymbol{x} \\
x & x \\
\end{array}\right]
\longrightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x & \boldsymbol{x} \\
\boldsymbol{x} &  \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

So that the full matrix ends being
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\boldsymbol{x} & x & x & x \\
 & \boldsymbol{x} & x & x  \\
 & & x & \boldsymbol{x} \\
 & & \boldsymbol{x} \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
but using a column transformation, which gives an equivalent system you would still get a triangular one. Moreover you can already use this matrix to solve it, but starting with the 3rd variable, not the 4th.